# Create shell script to append file count in a given directory name

Tags: bash, shell, rename

what I'im trying to do is make a simple shell script /bin/bash to count files in a given directory and then add the file count in the directory name.

I can imagine how to count files (with find) and even to store file count in a variable, but I cannot figure it out how to move into dir, then goes back, get the dir path and rename..

I usually use Platypus to convert a shell script into a OSX app, enabling drag&drop.

So the usage should be:

drag a folder into this app
the app count files into this folder
the app append file count into folder name

Any help will be appreciate

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Can You please post one example so it will be helpful

Comment: So if you add three files to a directory `xx` already containing two files, it gets progressively named like `xx_3_4_5` ?

Comment: As a side suggestion, do not rename the original directory. Create a symlink so that the symlink has the file count in it's name, and points to the original directory. So, ./mydir_11 -> ./mydir, and thus, you can still get to the original directory if something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can append the file count to the directory name as follows,
e.g. for a directory called `mydir`:

```bsh
mv ../mydir ../mydir$(ls | wc -l)
```

`ls | wc -l` gives you the file count in the current directory.

Or for an absolute path, the script could look something like this:

```bsh
path=/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/test
mv $path $path$(ls $path | wc -l)
```

Comment: Thanks Hector! Platypus pass the dropped folder as $1 to the script, so it will be mv ../$1 ../$1$(ls | wc -l)
correct?

Comment: That should work, let me know if it works out.

Comment: it does not :-( I tried this:

#!/bin/bash
echo "Append File Count"
echo "v.1.0"
mv $1 $1$(ls | wc -l)
it gives me:


​Append File Count
v.1.0
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: I have no experience with Platypus, but you should make sure
the script receives the correct paths. Not sure if Platypus passes an absolute path, but you could use absolute paths instead.

Comment: Thanks Hector, I did an echo $1 to see what platypus pass as an arg, it passes /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/test
is this an absolute path? how can I change it as an absolute?

Comment: That is an absolute path, I updated my answer using your path.

Comment: thanks hector, this works. I found the mv problem, need to be into "", so the script Is something like this now..

Answer (score 0):

this work :-)
thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Folder Name Append File Count"
echo "v.1.0"

cd "$1"

filecount=$(find . -type f -not -path "*/\.*" | wc -l)

mv "$1" "$1$filecount"
```